# Making a div fill the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an exceptionally easy thing to do, but its not working. I have a div inside the body element & it should be the width & height of the browser screen (minus the body's margin). But instead the div is only the height of 1 line (but has the correct width).

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/homepage.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        html, body, div, form, fieldset, legend, label, img {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;  }  table {  border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0; }  th, td {  text-align: left;  }  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, th, td, caption { font-weight:normal; }  img { border: 0; } 

        body { text-align: center;  background-color: RGB(255, 255, 255); margin: 20px; height: 100%; width: 100%; }

        #outerContainer { background-color: #DCFF9A; height: 100%; width: 100%; }

    -->
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    -->
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="outerContainer"> <!-- Why doesn't this div have the height & width of the whole screen? It's height appears to be one line -->
        <p id="testData"> abcd </p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the thing that is limiting you here is the height of the `html` element. the `body` element is set at 100% height but since it's container (`html`) doesn't have a height assigned, the body is only going to be 100% of the `html` height which is nothing

as suggested before by Ravan (+1) :), you need to set the html height to 100%. I usually also add the padding, margin and width 'resets' here also

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your css:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@mack; give `position absolute` to your div like this

```
#main{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```